# Data too long for column mysql

Tags: mysql, liferay

I am using Liferay framework with mysql database and i keep getting this error :

```
ERROR [http-bio-80-exec-5][render_portlet_jsp:157] com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'odlukaKomentar' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4118)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ClassLoaderSession.flush(ClassLoaderSession.java:237)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.BatchSessionImpl.update(BatchSessionImpl.java:86)
```

This field "odlukaKomentar" in database is LONGTEXT type. Any solution ?
Thanks

Comment: Which database you are using and  what is the length of your data?

Comment: I am using mysql data base and data was : odlukaKomentar=Partija 1:
1. Kilimandzaro 3.919.494,00

Partija  2:
1. Sefalosa 970.028,00
2. Ming 1.083.931,00

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html) (linking 5.0),

> LONGTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
>
> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (2^32 − 1)
>   characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains
>   multibyte characters. The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns
>   also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the
>   client/server protocol and available memory. Each LONGTEXT value is
>   stored using a 4-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes
>   in the value.

You might want to check the configuration of your database driver, the actual length (i doubt you come close to 4G bytes). If this is a service-builder component (because you're mentioning Liferay), you might want to google "liferay service builder model hints" and give service builder a better hint of the expected column sizes.

Comment: Is there any difference between TEXTAREA and CLOB type for String ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html
suggests a maximum length of 65,535 chars!

  
TEXT[(M)] [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]

A TEXT column with a maximum length of 65,535 (216 − 1) characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multibyte characters. Each TEXT value is stored using 2-byte length prefix that indicates number of bytes in value

An optional length M can be given for this type. If this is done, MySQL creates the column as the smallest TEXT type large enough to hold values M characters long